# find script making http requests from a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I loaded the following website in my browser.

```
http://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/
```

However, this in turn calls the webpage

```
http://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/IamAlive?t=1400181827732&1n26d5ar7d=1oh5lx7pr3
```

Just keeping the webpage open and monitoring the network traffic in charles, I see that the webpage makes continuous http requests like

```
http://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/IamAlive?t=1400180955743&12o8i06j23=t8ex3ekbx
http://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/IamAlive?t=1400845245363&12o8i0j236=tkl7thfnx
```

I looked at the html source and couldn't figure out what script in the webpage would be making these http requests. How can I find this?

I wanted to look at the script source so I can find the code and generate the

```
t=1400180955743
12o8i06j23=t8ex3ekbx
```

query parameters myself. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Your question does not quite fit the definition of good question for this site as it is not widely useful, somewhat broad, and the question by itself does not contain the necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `common.js` there is the function

```
function startIamAlive(){
    var timeout=5*60000;
    var fun=function(str){setTimeout(startIamAlive,timeout);};
    $.ajax({url:"IamAlive?t="+new Date().getTime(),success:fun,error:function(s){timeout=60000;fun(s);}});
}
```

there you can see how it works.